# Android: programmatically cut internet connection for the App

Tags: android

Is there a way to programatically **cut the internet connection only for my App** (not system wide!!) for a short period of time or close globally all current ongoing network connections of my App?

additional information from one of David's comments:

My use case is following: I am using a Library that starts a network connection and do some work, there is no possibility in the Lib to stop manually the transaction so the only workaorund would be to stop all connections made by the process of my App, I don't want cut the connection system wide.

Comment: If nothing else, information exposed by the /proc filesystem (or even perhaps simply iterative querying) would allow you to identify which currently open native file descriptors belonging to your process are network sockets, and perhaps forcibly close them.  But that would not stop new ones from being opened.

Answer (score -2):

You should write method, when check need or not execute Internet task (for example **AsyncTask**). Like:

```
  @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    if(isOnline()) {
      // your logic here
    } else {
      // other logic
    }
   }
```

Where **isOnline** method check need task execute or not.

EDIT:

For already running operations you need put method **isOnline** to other logic methods, like **postExecute**, if you set isOnline = off, on **postExecute** method nothing happened, if you also check like above.

For stops tasks, you should collect tasks and call **cancel(...)** method.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be proper answer. there is also issue of already running operations.

Comment: that doesn't solve it. postExecute is after it's finished. too late.

Comment: @Malachiasz why? Request will be done, but it did nothing, look above.

Comment: Indeed, this does nothing if you have code in some thread waiting on a blocking call, network related or otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, in AsyncTask it fits perfectly, also i edit answer for running tasks.

Comment: This answers don't relate to my question. My use case is following: I am using a Library that starts a network connection and do some work, there is no possibility in the Lib to stop manually the transaction so the only workaorund would be to stop all connections made by the process of my App, I don't want cut the connection system wide.

Comment: @David, i think, it is impossible do it without root.

Comment: @bkvirair - that is far from true.  Root is really only needed when you want to do something to a process belong to a *different* user.  As I have already explained in a comment, it is quite possible to close connections opened by other code running as part of the same process, because those sockets are owned by the same user, and because they are discovered either from /proc or simply by iteratively looking up all file descriptors.

Comment: Ok, then the solution would be too low level, not meaning with it that is would be to complicated for me, but meaning that the platform don't really support this case and the solution may also vary across the different Android versions.

Comment: No, this should be consistent across Android versions, as it comes from the Linux Kernel rather than the Android layer.